# Cannot seem to get this regular expression down

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string:

```
<a href="mailto:me@company.com">Joel Werner</a>
```

and I need to strip everything off but my name

The expression I have now, almost does that.

```
var pattern = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(">(?<name>.+?)<");
```

But when I match them I get

```
>Joel Werner<
```

What am I missing, because I do not really like regular expressions

Comment: You can get the named capture group out of that regex.

Comment: Unless you are parsing a very simple string like that, I suggest using an HTML parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use groups to get matched name:

```
var name = pattern.Match(input).Groups["name"].Value;
```

You can also verify `Success` of match before referencing group:

```
var match = pattern.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
    name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
```

Also you can reference group by index `Groups[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like regular expressions, don't use them in this case. Parsing HTML with regular expressions is usually very bad. See [this answer on why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery):

```
Console.WriteLine(CQ.Create("<a href=\"mailto:me@company.com\">Joel Werner</a>"). //create the selector
Attr("href"). //get the href attribute
Split(new char[]{':','@'})[1]); //split it by : and @ and take the second group (after the mailto)
```

Using built in LINQ to XML:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<a href=\"mailto:me@company.com\">Joel Werner</a>");
 Console.WriteLine(doc.Element("a").Attribute("href").ToString().Split(new char[] {':', '@'})[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex

```
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

then use 2nd match, first match is tag type.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "<a href=\"mailto:me@company.com\">Joel Werner</a>";
var pattern = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"<a\shref=""(?<url>.*?)"">(?<name>.*?)</a>");
var match = pattern.Match(input);
var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
```